# How to make a list of children widgets on a layout in QT?

Tags: qt, qlist

A nice simple example would be nice. For my part, I wish to do something like this:

```
myLayout->addWidget(myButton1);
myLayout->addWidget(myButton2);

myButtonList<QToolButtons*>->append(myLayout->findChildren(QToolButtons));

myButtonList->at(1)->setText("This is 'myButton2'");
```

Comment: `myLayout->itemAt(1)->widget()->setText("...");` just cast the result of `widget()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use QList along with using findChildren with QWidget because QLayout does not show QWidgets as its children and a QWidget have a parent QWidget only. [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518767/qt-findchild-returning-0)

```
QWidget w;
QPushButton *p1= new QPushButton;
QPushButton *p2= new QPushButton;
QHBoxLayout l;
l.addWidget(p1);
l.addWidget(p2);
w.setLayout(&l);
QList<QPushButton*> buttons = w.findChildren<QPushButton*>();
buttons.at(0)->setText("Hello I am P1"); 
buttons.at(1)->setText("Hello I am P2");
w.show();
```

Comment: That was probably the issue I was having, trying to find children directly on the layout. Good stuff

Comment: true, i forgot, widgets are parented to widgets, not the layout

Answer (score 5):

A lot easier would be the approach to first fill the list and afterwards the layout:

```
QList<QToolButton *> list;
list.append(new QToolButton);
list.last().setText("1");

myLayout->addWidget(list.last());
```

This could then also be easily looped for a higher amount of buttons.

You can still use

```
ParentWidget->findChildren<QToolButtons *>();
```

edited given vahancho hint for parent is always a widget, not the layout

Comment: Although the contents on my layout changes, you did give me an idea; The signal I use to move widgets onto the layout, I will also have them add to a list.

Comment: Is `myLayout->findChildren<QToolButtons *>();` valid call? Isn't `findChildren()` function member of rather QObject than QLayout class?

Comment: you're right, the parentwidget needs to be used, not the layout. Thx vahancho