# Finding a layout when knowing its name in Qt

Tags: qt, parent-child, qlayout

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518767/qt-findchild-returning-0), @cgmb mentioned that :

```
The parent of a `QWidget` must be a `QWidget`. `QLayout` is not a `QWidget`.

Layouts exist to move and resize the children of a `QWidget`. 
Though you may add child widgets by making calls on the layout, ultimately, 
    their parent will be the `QWidget` that the layout resides on.
```

For example, using `findChild()` like this to find a `QLayout` will return a `nullptr`:

```
QVBoxLayout *keyLayout = inputFieldGroupBox->findChild<QVBoxLayout*>("keyBoxLayoutCea", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
```

As such, I've been forced to use `itemAt()` to manually search for the layout:

```
QVBoxLayout *keyLayout = dynamic_cast<QVBoxLayout*>(firstHoriField->itemAt(3)->layout());
```

(`firstHoriField` is a layout in which `keyLayout` locates in, and `inputFieldGroupBox` is a `QGroupBox` which `firstHoriField` locates in)

Is there any efficient/less prone to bug method which can be used to find a layout (knowing its name), because from the code above, it could be seen that the `itemAt()` method is rather bruteforce-y, and if for some reason I change the indexes (for instance from `3`->`2`), the program wouldn't run.

Comment: Check [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3077307/1559401).

Comment: @rbaleksandar Hmm, from that I can deduce that `itemAt()` is the most feasible way of find layouts currently?